# Which event should be using for save product in administrator interface?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want add some adjustments when I edit a single product in administrator.
Which event should I use for that (on save product)?

Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to override the `sw-product-detail` component and the `onSave` method to make some changes prior to calling the original method.

```js
Shopware.Component.override('sw-product-detail', {
    methods: {
        onSave() {
            this.product.somePropertyToChange = 'foobar';
            
            this.$super('onSave');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to match that via Subscriber/Event instead of `sw-product-detail` component?